# Migrating TextField() to JSONField()

Tags: python, django

I used to have a `TextField(blank=True, default='')` in my model. Due some changes in the requirements of the project, it now become a better idea to have a dict stored, something like this:

```
instructions {
    wait_time: {
        active: True
        message: 'This is a standard message'
    }
}
```

So I changed it to a JSONField: `JSONField(blank=True, null=True)`. Did the changes in the serializers, and it passed on on the test for that specific field.  When I tried to run the rest of the suit, I got this error:

```
AssertionError: {u'non_field_errors': [u'null value in column "instructions" violates not-null constraint\n
```

Which makes a lot of sense, since the TextField was set `null=False`. This field should now accept null values. I imagined that `makemigrations` and `migrate` would do the job.

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:
```

My first idea was regarding the default value set for the TextField() before. To test it, I reverted the migration to the moment before its creation, delete the new migrations, 'mademigrations' and ran the tests. For some weird reasons, I still got: 'violates not-null constraint' error. This lead me to think the problem is not in the in the TextField() set as null=False before. If that's the case, those two problems might be unrelated to each other. Either way, I'm clueless on how to proceed.

Comment: The problem is that the `TextField` was set to `null=True`, and it is not clear how to migrate such `null` values. A straightforward candidate is of course the `'null'` JSON blob.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you please give more details?

Comment: Did you find your answer? I'm encountering the same issue. Below answer didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.
This it due to TextField set to `null=True`.
Just change your `NULL` field to `"null"` and it will works like a charm.